# shell bash script - upload a big tar file, retry?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I use the following shell script code to upload a big .tar file. Sometimes it happens that the server can´t resolve the domain to the ip or the other server isn´t available. So I wan´t it to retry some times if it didn´t work. How can I do this? I couldn´t find something for this on the internet.

```
ftp -inv << EOF
  open $FTP_SERVER
  user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS
  cd $FTP_VERZEICHNIS
  mkdir ultimate_$DATE
  cd ultimate_$DATE
  mput *.tar
  quit
EOF
```

---

**Edit:**

Sorry I have no real experience with shell, how would this look like ?

```
FTP_SUCCESS_MSG="226 Transfer complete"
while [fgrep "$FTP_SUCCESS_MSG" $FTPLOG]
do
FTPLOG=/temp/ftplogfile
ftp -inv <<! > $FTPLOG
  open $FTP_SERVER
  user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS
  cd $FTP_VERZEICHNIS
  mkdir ultimate_$DATE
  cd ultimate_$DATE
  mput *.tar
  close
  quit
!
fi
exit 0
sleep 10s
else    
   echo "Upload completed"
done
```

Comment: Something like `while [ $i -le 5 ]; do .... sleep 10; ((i++)); done`?

Comment: yeah and how do I get if the connection failed ?

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899316/getting-exit-status-code-from-ftp-command-in-linux-shell

Comment: @fedorqui Hey, I updated the question, could you check it out ? I tried to solve it with the other stackoverflow question, but it looks like my knwolege isn´t enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting from your code and the one in [Getting exit status code from 'ftp' command in linux shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899316/getting-exit-status-code-from-ftp-command-in-linux-shell) I made this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FTP_SUCCESS_MSG="226 Transfer complete"
FTPLOG=/temp/ftplogfile

i=0
while [ $i -le 5 ]; do

ftp -inv <<! > $FTPLOG
  open $FTP_SERVER
  user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS
  cd $FTP_VERZEICHNIS
  mkdir ultimate_$DATE
  cd ultimate_$DATE
  mput *.tar
  close
  quit
!

  if fgrep "$FTP_SUCCESS_MSG" $FTPLOG ;then
    i=10    #stupid way of saying: exit the "while"
  else
    sleep 5
    i=expr $i + 1     # ((i++)) not working
  fi

done
```

Comment: thank your, but I get an unexpected fi:     Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "done")

Comment: Oh, there were a `fi` too much. Check it again and see.

Comment: Add a `#!/bin/bash` in the first line and execute.

Comment: mhh, it still doesn´t work. The log shows "No Connection" and the script freezes.

Comment: I don't have a `ftp` server to try, so I suggest you to check it in yours. I just put together your idea and the other script, but cannot go any further :) Success!

Comment: Name or service not known/path/file.sh: 54: i++: not found

Comment: You can use `i=$((i + 1))` instead, as it auto increments.